# How to Get Total number of streets from Google Map , from given area by using Rectangle or polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I want to count number of streets from google map which is in between Rectangle or polygon[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlMJX.png)
[image]

[image]

Comment: That functionality is not supported by the API

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer @geocodezip
Is there any other way instead of (google map SDK or API) to do this functionality.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow